# Add custom attribute to category collection - magento 2.3

Tags: magento-2.3

I created a new attribute as this tutorial: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html.

This works fine, but the attribute is not present in category collection, on frontend.

```
$block is \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
```

and

```
$block->getCurrentCategory()->getData(), does not contain my attribute.
```

Where this attribute must be specified to be loaded on init collection?

Answer (score 0):

My bad ..., I did not run attribute reindexing. Now works fine.